# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep') when mount function from "vue/test-utils" is called with a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, quasar, vitest

**DESCRIPTION**

Hello! I'm working in a quasar project migrating from jest to vitest and my old test were working perfectly, but when i installed vitest one of those test failed even after refactor... It seems to be a problem with the mount method from "vue/test-utils"
`import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";`
with a Vue component called Login
 `import Login from "src/modules/auth/views/LoginPersonal.vue";`

**LOGIN COMPONENT**

```html
<template>
  <div class="fullscreen my-background flex justify-center items-center">
    <q-card
      class="my-card my-container my-background text-white flex no-wrap column items-center justify-between"
    >
      <q-card-section>
        <h1 class="text-h3 text-indigo-2">Inicio de sesión</h1>
      </q-card-section>

      <q-card-section
        class="q-pa-md fit column justify-between items-center"
        style="width: 100%"
      >
        <div class="q-gutter-md" style="max-width: 400px">
          <q-form
            ref="form"
            data-test="submit"
            @submit.prevent="
              logIn({ email: email, password: password, rol: 'users' })
            "
          >
            <q-input
              v-model.trim="email"
              class="q-mb-md"
              filled
              placeholder="Email"
              :dense="true"
              style="width: 300px"
              :rules="[
                (val) => (val && val.length > 0) || 'Por favor coloca un email',
              ]"
            />
            <q-input
              v-model.trim="password"
              class="q-mb-md"
              filled
              placeholder="Contraseña"
              :dense="true"
              style="width: 300px"
              :rules="[
                (val) =>
                  (val && val.length > 0) || 'Por favor coloca una contraseña',
              ]"
            />
            <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-xs" color="grey-4" v-if="loadingState">
              <div
                class="q-gutter-md row justify-center"
                style="font-size: 5em"
              >
                <q-spinner-gears color="cyan" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <q-btn
              :ripple="true"
              color="secondary"
              style="width: 300px"
              label="Iniciar sesión"
              type="submit"
              no-caps
              v-else
            />
          </q-form>
          <q-item clickable v-ripple to="/registro">
            ¿No te has registrado? ¡Haz click aqui!
          </q-item>
        </div>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { useLogUser } from "../hooks/useLogUser";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();

    const { logIn, loadingState, email, password } = useLogUser(store);

    return { logIn, loadingState, email, password };
  },
};
</script>
<style lang="css" scoped>
.my-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I'm mocking all my hooks/composables correctly and i dont know where is the property "deep" that the error shows me. As i said... It was working perfectly with jest; this is the error that appears when `mount(Login)` is called:

**ERROR**

```
FAIL  test/jest/__tests__/modules/auth/views/Login.spec.js > Login view > Debe llamar al metodo Login cuando se hace click
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'deep')
 ❯ Module.withDirectives node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:2754:17
 ❯ ../../../../src/modules/auth/views/LoginPersonal.vue:117:37
 ❯ renderFnWithContext node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:847:21
 ❯ normalizeChildren node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6847:42
 ❯ createBaseVNode node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6600:9
 ❯ _createVNode node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6702:12
 ❯ Module.createVNodeWithArgsTransform node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6558:12
 ❯ ../../../../src/modules/auth/views/LoginPersonal.vue:111:31
 ❯ renderFnWithContext node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:847:21
 ❯ normalizeChildren node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6847:42
```

**VITEST FILE**

```js
/**
 * @vitest-environment happy-dom
 */
import Login from "src/modules/auth/views/LoginPersonal.vue";
import { describe, expect, test, vi, beforeEach } from "vitest";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

let mockLogIn = vi.fn();

vi.mock("src/modules/auth/hooks/useLogUser", () => ({
  useLogUser: () => ({
    logIn: mockLogIn,
    loadingState: false,
    email: "",
    password: "",
  }),
}));

const mockStore = {
  dispatch: vi.fn(),
  getters: {
    "user/currentStatus": "authenticated",
    "user/currentUser": {
      name: "test",
      email: "test@test.com",
    },
  },
};
vi.mock("vuex", () => ({
  useStore: () => mockStore,
}));
describe("Login view", () => {
  
  test("Debe llamar al metodo Login cuando se hace click", async () => {
    console.log(mount(Login));
  });
});
```